# jquery load multiple blocks in Django

Tags: jquery, django, load, block

I am trying to load the content of each page of my website when I click on a link in my menu, without reloading the whole page (so without reloading my header and menu). Here is my code:

**base.html**

```
<div id="container-fluid">
    <!-- header -->
    <div class="row_fluid">
        <header >
            blablabla
        </header>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- left menu -->
        <div class="span3">
            <div id="menu">
                <a id="login">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- content -->
        <div class="span9">
            <!-- title of the page -->
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <h3>{% block contentTitle %}{% endblock %}</h3>
            </div>

            <!-- right-side content -->
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div id="content">
                    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block contentTitle %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    blablabla
{% endblock %}
```

When I click on "Log in", I would like to get the content of index.html and **load both the blocks contentTitle and content** in my div content.

So far, here is what I have in JS:

**jquey.js**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#login").click(function()
    {
        $("#content").load("/website/login/");
    });

});
```

This code loads the whole page, which means it loads base.html, so I now have twice the header and the menu on my page! And it doesn't take care of my block contentTitle, but I don't know how to do that. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adam, I don't know how to adapt your code to more than one element. So I used a different method and it works :)... But the css is messed up :(. Here is my code:

**base.html**

```
...
<!-- menu -->
<a id="login" href="{% url login %}">
...
<!-- Body content -->
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 first_row">
        <!-- title of the page -->
        <h3 id="title_base">{% block contentTitle %}{% endblock %}</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <!-- right-side content -->
        <div id="content_base">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block contentTitle %}<div id="title">Login</div>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content">
        blablabla
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**jquery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#login').click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("/website/login/", function(data)
        {
            var title=$(data).find("#title");
            var content=$(data).find("#content");
            $("#title_base").html(title);
            $("#content_base").html(content);
        });
    });
});
```

The css is almost ok but there is a small problem:

**Without jQuery**
[image: Without JQuery]

**With jQuery**
[image: With JQuery]

Do you need my css to detect what's wrong? When I check the css of my legend "Please login below", I see no difference between the 2 pages (I use the Developer tools of Chrome).

Here is the css of my legend:

```
/* override bootstrap */
legend
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width:auto;
    padding:0 1%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

In the web developer tool of Chrome: if I deactivate the width, the text is contained in one line only but there is no upper border. If I active the width again, then both the text and border are normally displayed (as in the first picture)! Is it a bug? Notice that I override the default css of bootstrap (width: 100%).

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help (from [the "Loading Page Fragments" section of jQuery's `.load()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)):

> The `.load()` method, unlike [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the `url` parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document that is fetched:
>
> ```
> $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
> ```
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of `ajax/test.html`, but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of `container`. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the element with an ID of `result`, and the rest of the retrieved document is discarded.
>
> jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

I'd like to reiterate this part:

> ***This element*, along with its contents**, is inserted into the element